# Using query result within another query

Tags: magento-1.9, database

This is an odd question, as it's something I've done countless times in the past. I'm simply running a query and returning a single result using `fetchOne()`, and then using the result in a new query. The issue here is that the query isn't reading the result, despite the result being there.

The two queries:

```
$current_order_query = "SELECT billing_name FROM $table WHERE customer_id = 7324 ORDER BY increment_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$current_billing_name = $readConnection->fetchOne($current_order_query);

$second_query = "SELECT billing_name FROM $table2 WHERE billing_name LIKE '$current_billing_name'";
$second_billing_name = $readConnection->fetchOne($second_query);
```

What's confusing me, even more, is that I can simply `echo` the `$current_billing_name` and it returns the result just fine as a string. I tried manually entering a string into the second query to see if it was that, but the query worked then. The first query is indeed returning the result correctly, but the second query is simply not taking it.

(The purpose of the queries is to find the billing name of the current order, and then run a check for matches in a custom blacklist)

Hopefully, someone can spot something I'm completely overlooking before I pull the rest of my hair out.

EDIT:

```
if(!$second_billing_name){
    // Nothing found, continue to next thing
} else {
    // Billing name found in the blacklist, email admin
}
```

Comment: What are table variables?

Comment: `$table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_grid');`
`$table2 = $resource->getTableName('blacklist');`

Comment: Have you considered using a join to link two tables together and do as single query?

Comment: I've considered it, but haven't really thought it out since the tables have no common column except for the `billing_name` which may not even have a matching key. Could you give an example? I've updated the OP with what I'm doing after this query.

Comment: I was maybe thinking something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10022406/10121426

Comment: Thanks, this would work using `EXISTS`. Still bugs me not knowing why this one single query wasn't working, especially when I have multiple other ones in the same file like it and they work just fine.